# How to connect to MS SQL using integrated security from Linux in Spring boot?

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-security-kerberos

I know that there is a way using kerberos to connect to MS SQL Server. But I have not been able to find a good description on how to configure everything from Kereberos to the properties file's url. Does anyone have a good example that could teach the rest?

Comment: check it out http://seenukarthi.com/security/2014/08/13/localhost-authentication-spring-kerberos/

Comment: Thanks, but the link shows how to use kerberos for authenticating users. I guess many of the things are reusable, but I was looking for something simpler. I will dig into it see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Keyhan did you find something? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074354/spring-boot-mysql-kerberos-authentication ?

Comment: No, not really. But I am now working with something totally different.