# Spring Boot MSSQL Kerberos Authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, kerberos

Currently in my spring boot `application.properties` file, I am specifying following lines to connect to MSSql server.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=springbootd

spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.datasource.password=Projects@123
```

Instead of giving username and password, I want to authenticate user using kerberos, what all changes I will have to make.

I tried searching in the JPA official documentation but could not find any. Leads here are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#ssk-spnego

Comment: This is too much of a detail.

Comment: @Naveen that documentation is only for enabling authentication into a Spring app via Kerberos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, you need to set up your `krb5.conf` file properly. You can verify that configuration via the following command and entering your password:

```
kinit <user-name>
```

Additionally, make sure you have a JDBC URL like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://servername=server_name;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;userName=user@REALM;password=****
```

See [Microsoft JDBC driver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for details.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention the startup arguments. Add the following JVM argument:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=<PATH_TO>/krb5.conf
```

I believe this is not neccessary if you use the default `krb5.conf` but not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks, Does JDBC URL needs userName=user@REALM;password=****?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, but not entirely sure. The `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` properties should take care of that.

Comment: There is no point in adding configuration "spring.datasource.username=sa" and "spring.datasource.password=Projects@123" because that is what we are trying to prevent by using kerberos. I awarded you a bounty because it would have expired in next 24 hours and would not have been useful post that. I summary, I still didn't get any satisfiable answer, to me it looks like you are thinking "username" and "password" are required even if we use kerberos.

Comment: As per my understanding adding "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://servername=server_name;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;" should work. But this needs testing from my end.

Comment: `username` and `password` should be required when (i) the app is running in an OS where Kerberos logon is not configured or (ii) you want a DB connection with different credentials than the user's login credentials. It ultimately depends on your use case.